# Call jpegOptim with RedirectStandardInput and RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, process, stream, redirectstandardoutput, jpegoptim

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be relatively simple: Call jpegoptim from C#.

I can get it to write to disk fine, but getting it to accept a stream and emit a stream has so far eluded me - I always end up with 0 length output or the ominous "Pipe has been ended."

One approach I tried:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessInfo(
    jpegOptimPath,
    "-m" + quality + " -T1 -o -p --strip-all --all-normal"
);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

using(var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        inputStream.CopyToAsync(process.StandardInput.BaseStream),
        process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream)
    );

    while (!process.HasExited)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    // Do stuff with outputStream here - always length 0 or exception
}
```

I've also tried this solution:

http://alabaxblog.info/2013/06/redirectstandardoutput-beginoutputreadline-pattern-broken/

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    process.Start();

    //Thread.Sleep(100);

    using (Task processWaiter = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.WaitForExit()))
    using (Task<string> outputReader = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()))
    using (Task<string> errorReader = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()))
    {
        Task.WaitAll(processWaiter, outputReader, errorReader);

        standardOutput = outputReader.Result;
        standardError = errorReader.Result;
    }
}
```

Same problem. Output length 0. If I let jpegoptim run without the output redirect I get what I'd expect - an optimized file - but not when I run it this way.

There's gotta be a right way to do this?

Update: Found a clue - don't I feel sheepish - jpegoptim never supported piping to stdin until an experimental build in 2014, fixed this year. The build I have is from an older library, dated 2013. https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution - see deadlock issue below. I had multiple problems in my original attempts:

1. You need a build of jpegoptim that will read and write to pipes instead of files-only. As mentioned [builds prior to mid-2014 can't do it](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim/issues/6). The github "[releases](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim/releases)" of jpegoptim are useless zips of source, not built releases, so you'll need to look elsewhere for actual [built releases](https://www.kapadiya.net/jpegoptim-win32/binaries.html).
2. You need to call it properly, passing `--stdin` and `--stdout`, and depending on how you'll be responding to it, avoid parameters that might cause it to write nothing, like -T1 (which will, when optimization is going to only be 1% or less, cause it to emit nothing to stdout).
3. You need to perform the non-trivial task of: Redirecting both input and output on the Process class
4. and avoiding a Buffer overflow on the input side that will get you 0 output once again - the obvious stream.CopyToAsync() overruns Process's very limited 4096 byte (4K) buffer and gets you nothing.

So many routes to nothing. None signalling why.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessInfo(
    jpegOptimPath,
    "-m" + quality + " --strip-all --all-normal --stdin --stdout",
);

processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

using(var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = processInfo;

    process.Start();

    int chunkSize = 4096;   // Process has a limited 4096 byte buffer
    var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int bufferLen = 0;
    var inputStream = process.StandardInput.BaseStream;
    var outputStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

    do
    {
        bufferLen = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        await inputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
        inputStream.Flush();
    }
    while (bufferLen == chunkSize);

    do
    {
        bufferLen = await outputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        if (bufferLen > 0)
            await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
    }
    while (bufferLen > 0);

    while(!process.HasExited)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    output.Flush();
```

There are some areas for improvement here. Improvements welcome.

- Biggest problem: On some images, this deadlocks on the outputStream.ReadAsync line.
- It all belongs in separate methods to break it up - I unrolled a bunch of methods to keep this example simple.
- There are a bunch of flushes that may not be necessary.
- The code here is meant to handle anything that streams in and out. The 4096 is a hard limit that any Process will deal with, but the assumption that all the input goes in, then all the output comes out is likely a bad one and based on my research could result in a deadlock for other types of process. It appears that jpegoptim behaves in this (very buffered, very unpipe-like...) way when passed --stdin --stdout however, so, this code copes well for this specific task.